# Not able to push SQL Query result to an array in node js

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm trying to push the results of an SQL query to an array. However, it doesn't seem to be working. There was no solution online that I could find. If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
        let data = [];
        connection.query("SELECT DISTINCT referer FROM publisher", (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            results.forEach(async (result) => {
                let referer = result.referer;
                let today = new Date();
                for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                    let hour = i;
                    let start = new Date(today);
                    start.setHours(hour, 0, 0, 0);
                    let end = new Date(today);
                    end.setHours(hour, 59, 59, 999);
                    connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM publisher WHERE referer = ? AND first_seen >= ? AND first_seen <= ?", [referer, start, end], (error, results) => {
                        if (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        } else {
                            let count = results[0].count;
                            data.push({
                                referer: referer,
                                hour: hour,
                                count: count
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you get any error during execution?

Comment: Nope. I get empty array

Comment: Have you tried to log the results of the queries?

Comment: when I log results inside query. It works fine. I'm not able to bring those results out of query.

Comment: okay, so `count` remain Undefined? have you tried using `console.table` it helps a lot with arrays and structures

Comment: Nope. count doesn't remain undefined. the entire object inside the query works just fine. I get the exact thing I want. The problem is when I push the object into data array outside of query. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a single query to get data from MySql DB

```
select referer, hour(first_seen) h, count(*) n
from publisher
where date(first_seen) = curdate()
group by referer, hour(first_seen)
order by referer, hour(first_seen)
```

This way eliminating inner async method in js code.

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I now get error in console `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Comment: `let data = connection.query("SELECT referer, HOUR(first_seen) AS hour, COUNT(*) AS count FROM publisher WHERE date(first_seen) = CURDATE() GROUP BY referer, HOUR(first_seen)");
        res.send(data);`

Comment: Not sure about JS but my guess is you should use  the `.query` method the way similar to OP,  `connection.query("SELECT ..", (error, results) => {..}`  and send result within a callback.